# App can be found by author but not name

Tags: android, google-play

Hi thanks for taking the time to read. I made an app (a game) called Stars and Planets and it can be found under the author name which is "Jedakiah" but it can not be found under its game name. Why could this be happening? Thanks.

Comment: Google's search algorithms are mysterious things.

Comment: "Stars and Planets" is a common phrase so its less likely to come up than something unique.

Comment: when did you publish your app?

Answer (score 0):

Putting the search term in quotes seems to show it just fine: [https://play.google.com/store/search?q="Stars and Planets"](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=%22Stars%20and%20Planets%22)

If you don't use quotes, it's searching for the terms 'Stars', likely ignoring the common word 'and' and also searching [but not exclusively] for 'Planets'